# Which comics should I read to get the "full" Harley Quinn story?

Tags: dc

I've heard some stories go around that at one point Harley was pregnant, and at one point she realized the Joker was abusing her and left him.

I don't know if these are true. But if I wanted read the "full" story, which comics would I need to do that?

Sorry if this is a bit vague.

Comment: In case you didn't know, she was actually invented for the DCAU.

Answer (score 1):

Harley was first introduced in the comics main continuity in No Man's Land. A full year arc that crossed over many comics in the Bat-family. Harley's relationship is explored in Gotham City Sirens vis a vi Ivy, Harvey, and Catwoman live together and support each other. After that short run she has her solo comic series.

I don't know where or if there was a pregnancy story. I don't remember it. Harley is a fun character that shows up from time to time in the Bat Comics, but she usually doesn't get more than a single issue dedicated to her or is a secondary to a Joker story, so I don't have a full memory of those outtings off the top of my head, but I'll look into it more later and edit if noone has provided a better or in general answer to when/if that happened.

New 52 Harley I can only point you to Suicide Squad. Harley didn't appear in anything else I know at least up to the end of 2013 in new 52, but again I'll look into it.

Edit: After coming back and looking it up [HERE](http://comicvine.gamespot.com/harley-quinn/4005-1696/) I pretty much covered everything. That site provides a list of every appearance of the character and a full history. it unfortunately doesn't cite in the history when/where it takes place.